# Spark partitionBy | save by column value rather than columnName={value}

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using scala and spark, my spark version is 2.4.3

My dataframe looks like this, there are other columns which i have not put and is not relavent.

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
|ts_utc_yyyy|ts_utc_MM|ts_utc_dd|
+-----------+---------+---------+
|2019       |01       |20       |
|2019       |01       |13       |
|2019       |01       |12       |
|2019       |01       |19       |
|2019       |01       |19       |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Basically i want to store the data in a bucketed format like

> 2019/01/12/*data*
>
> 2019/01/13/*data*
>
> 2019/01/19/*data*
>
> 2019/01/20/*data*

I am using following code snippet

> ```
>   df.write
>   .partitionBy("ts_utc_yyyy","ts_utc_MM","ts_utc_dd")
>     .format("csv")
>     .save(outputPath)
> ```

But the problem is it is getting stored along with the column name like below.

> ts_utc_yyyy=2019/ts_utc_MM=01/ts_utc_dd=12/*data*
>
> ts_utc_yyyy=2019/ts_utc_MM=01/ts_utc_dd=13/*data*
>
> ts_utc_yyyy=2019/ts_utc_MM=01/ts_utc_dd=19/*data*
>
> ts_utc_yyyy=2019/ts_utc_MM=01/ts_utc_dd=20/*data*

how do i save without column name in the folder name ?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are trying to store on HDFS. is it correct ?

Comment: Well I am using Google storage service for saving files In production. The same behavior is seen in development machine  file system ( Mac )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. Spark uses Hive partitioning so it writes using this convention, which enables partition discovery, filtering and pruning. In short, it optimises your queries by ensuring that the minimum amount of data is read.

Spark isn't really designed for the output you need. The easiest way for you to solve this is to have a downstream task that will simply rename the directories by splitting on the equals sign.